# Pictures in square moving back in Word 2003

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2003

I have a few pages in which I have a lot of text, and 2 textboxes per page and 2 pictures. I have set the picture layout to `Square` so my text will wrap around it.

I've added a header and footer, and after that I noticed all my pictures are out of place. So then I started fixing that.

When I moved the one picture to the place I wanted it to be, I started moving the second picture. As soon as I released that picture (to place that picture there), my first picture got set to the previous, wrong place. If I move that first picture again, the same happens to my second.

I can't format my Word document like this. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the two images?

Comment: They are just two images of fingerprint readers, with next to it text explaining their functionality. It happens on any page and also at an other document. I think this went wrong when I inserted a header and/or footer. I've tried to reformat it in Word 2010 but the problem persists. I'm now going to put everything in invisible tables instead but it seems to me its a bug or something.

Comment: It's very hard to work out what could be wrong with such little information but I would suggest to turn on Show Formatting Marks and fiddle with the anchors of each image (click on the image and you will see a little anchor icon next to a line of text, drag this to a different paragraph). Make sure that the anchors of both images are in separate paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the tip given by Adam in the comments, this also worked for me:

What you need to do is right-click on the picture and select `Format Picture`. Click on the `Layout` tab. Click on the `Advanced` button. Click on the `Picture Position` tab. Under both the `Horizontal` and `Vertical` selections, select `Absolute Position`, and pick `Page` from the drop-down menu at the right. Also, click on the checkbox that says `Lock anchor.` Now, your pictures won't move around the page.